# how to run super user commands in java?

Tags: java, command, runtime

i am running one (Runtime)sample java program in IDE. 
i am not getting anything in my console.

The program is to execute the super user commands.

```
 try {
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c xl list");  // or "sudo xl list"
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line = null;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
}
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

^ xl list is the super user command.

how to call this one. or give me suggestion to call "ipconfig" command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are getting an error, or su is asking you for a password

I suggest you

- read error messages
- using `sudo` in a way that doesn't require a password.

Comment: peter : sudo is giving blank screen its not showing any error or output. i tried "sudo xl list". but normal commands like ls are working..

Comment: And you made sure you can use `sudo` for this command without a password.

Comment: Or can you set uid the command as root on your system (not as secure)

Comment: i run that ide as root user it works. now only i tried. but i have to achieve this by program itself i.e., running the program it have to give the output.

Comment: How have you configured `sudo`?